# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduction' while trying to load keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to load a Keras sequential model and get some error of unexpected keyword `reduction`.

Here's the code:

I've trained the following Sequential model:

```py
model = Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(in_dim,)),
    layers.Dense(
    units=(in_dim+1),
    activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.01)
    ),
    layers.Dropout(rate=.05),
    layers.Dense(
    units=(in_dim),
    activation=layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.01)
    ),
    layers.Dropout(rate=.05),
    layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")
])
```

and compile and fit it by [Keras's tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#training_procedure):

```py
def compile_and_fit(
    model,
    name,
    X_y_train,
    X_y_val,
    optimizer=None,
    max_epochs=10000,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
):

    X_train, y_train = X_y_train
    steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // batch_size
    X_val, y_val = X_y_val
    steps_per_epoch_val = len(X_val) // batch_size

    if optimizer is None:
        optimizer = get_optimizer(steps_per_epoch)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(name="binary_crossentropy"),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name="precision"),
            "accuracy",
        ],
    )

    model.summary()

    history = model.fit(
        x=X_train,
        y=y_train,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=max_epochs,
        validation_data=X_y_val,
        validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_val,
        callbacks=get_callbacks(name),
        verbose=1,
    )
    return history
```

And at the end saving the model:

```
model.save(f"./saved_model/my_model", save_format="tf")
```

But When I tried to load it:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./saved_model/my_model")
```

And got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [25], line 2
----> 2 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./saved_model/my_model")

File /mnt/c/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /mnt/c/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/dtensor/utils.py:144, in inject_mesh.<locals>._wrap_function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    142 if mesh is not None:
    143     instance._mesh = mesh
--> 144 init_method(instance, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduction'
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You are using a loss instance in `metrics()`. Try to change into: `metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name="binary_crossentropy") ... ]`

Comment: Wow, thank you it works now!! They have to fix the tutorial